Unexpected Thread Behavior with subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()) in Spring Boot Reactive Programming
I am using getAPI in Spring Boot with reactive programming. While applying subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()), I expect the thread to be bounded elastic. However, instead of that, I am getting:
all-book-details: http-nio-8081-exec-1
book-details1: http-nio-8081-exec-1

This is after applying a log to check the thread.
I have a condition where I do not want to use publishOn()
@GetMapping
public Flux<Book> getAll() {
  logger.info("all-book-details: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
  return bookService.getAll().subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
}

    @Override
    public Flux<Book> getAll() {
        logger.info("book-details1: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return bookRepository
                .findAll()
                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                .log()
                .map(book -> {
                    book.setName(book.getName().toUpperCase());
                    return book;           
                });
    }

public Flux<Book> getAll();

@Table("book")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builderpublic
class Book {
  @Id
  @Column("book_id")
  private int bookId;
  @Column("NAME")
  private String name;
  @Column("book_desc")
  private String description;  
  private String publisher;  
  private String author;
}

expected output is bounded elastic
but got all-book-details: http-nio-8081-exec-1
book-details1: http-nio-8081-exec-1

You call logger.info in your method itself, not inside the reactive execution. So it would have the same thread as the caller.
If you want to check what is the thread for the Reactive flux, do it inside one its handlers. For example inside doOnSubscribe:
public Flux<Book> getAll() {
    return bookRepository
            .findAll()
            .doOnSubscribe((s) -> {
               logger.info("book-details1: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            })
            .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
            .log()
            .map(book -> {
                book.setName(book.getName().toUpperCase());
                return book;           
            });
}


i want to know difference between map and flatmap in the reactive programming,
because after using flatmap the there is change in the thread

flatMap makes a new Publisher, which may be subscribed from another thread.
